# Crosswalk : build for android api 15

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I need to target an android 4.0.4 device with crosswalk, on a ionic app.

In my config.xml, I have :

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15"/>
```

With `ionic run android`, crosswalk run into an error and ask me for a minimal android version of 16.

Is there a way to get it working with the android api 15 ?
Thanks

---EDIT
With `Ionic browser list` I have the following version of crosswalk avalaible.

```
Available - Crosswalk - ionic browser add crosswalk
             Version 8.37.189.14 Published
             Version 9.38.208.10 Published
             Version 10.39.235.15 Published
             Version 11.40.277.7 Published
             Version 12.41.296.5 Published
    (beta)   Version 13.42.319.6 Published
    (canary) Version 14.42.334.0 Published
```

I tried all versions, all of them get the same error.
I noticed that they all install this plugin `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.1.0`, that might be a part of the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063792/build-error-after-adding-crosswalk-plugin-to-a-cordova-android-project?rq=1).
1/ add `<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="17+" />` to config.xml
2/ follow the badboyunited solution : remove android platform, add crosswalk plugin via cordova, add android platform.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a version 19 or earlier of Crosswalk, I suppose, but as of version 20, the Crosswalk team no longer supports Android < 4.1. See https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/deprecate-40.html for the announcement.

Comment: I can't find in Ionic a suitable version, see my edit.

Comment: I'm not sure if Ionic's version is the same as the version I'd add with Cordova. I suggest starting with version 12.41.xxx and working backward until you find one that works for your needs.

Comment: I tried all of those versions, I still have the same error. See edit again.